# c# enum description degree

Tags: c#, .net, enums

How can I declare ° instead of degree in an enum?

```
//tilts declaration
    public enum Tilts
    {
        mm = 0,
        ° = 1, //degree
        inch = 2
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible, but personally I would suggest you don't! If you want to be able to easily output it in a string form, I'd look into adding an extension method to the enum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow up on my comment, you should probably instead add an extension method to the `enum` to provide the formatted string you need:

```
public enum Tilts
{
    Mm = 0,
    Degree = 1,
    Inch = 2
}

public static class TiltsExtensions
{
    public static string ToSymbol(this Tilts tilts)
    {
        switch (tilts)
        {
            default: return tilts.ToString();
            case Tilts.Degree: return "°";
            // etc;
        }
    }
}
```

Then whenever you want to output the symbol form, just use the method like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(tilts.ToSymbol());
```